Remove NGINX header before processing
I have an nginx 1.24.0 running and a client software that sends both Content-Length and Transfer-Encoding: Chunked headers by mistake. This leads to a 400 Bad Request response.
Unfortunately, I cannot update the client software. Is there a way to remove the Content-Length header, before it is processed by nginx, so that the request is working? In former versions of nginx this was working.
